# Синонимизировать [диаграммы] и [chart]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать метки

- [диаграммы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b) (45 вопросов, описания нет)
- [chart](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart) (192 вопроса, есть описание)

Описание метки [chart](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart) явно показывает что они об одном и том же:

> Диаграмма - это ...

Основная - [диаграммы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b), т. к. она на русском.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 202 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 192 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 188 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'chart': [chart] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 233
tag remapping of [диаграммы] and [chart] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
35 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym chart -> диаграммы was approved!
```